# How do I get Deoxys in Pokemon Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When I searched Google, there were articles and forum posts on how to change Deoxys' form, but not how to actually obtain one!

Is this possible?

Comment: But how is there guides on how to change its form in x and y? Im so confused!

Comment: Cause you can still have it in the game. You can trade it over. You just can't get it in X and Y

Comment: Well crap... I have no one to trade with and there's no connection point nearby...:C

Comment: Because it can be transferred up from gen 3 all the way to XY/ORAS - so they included a way to change its form for those who transferred it.

Comment: Side question: how do I get mew two after making it faint first?

Comment: If you have another question, feel free to ask another one by hitting the "ask Question" button.

Comment: Why does this website hate humor and won't let me make people smile? I like to reply to questions with things to make them laugh! What's wrong with that?

Comment: @SheogorathGaming In short, noise to signal ratios. You ever attempt to find some information on a forum, but the only thread that is asking for the information you need is filled with "me too", crude adult humor, and name calling? That's all noise. While the answer (the signal) is buried on page 11 of 13. You could easily miss that answer while skimming all the nonsense. The goal of the StackExchange network is to cut through the noise, and achieve strong signals. Thus, a **question** has an **answer**. While there is a little leeway in the comments sections -

Comment: Even comments are trimmed now and then when they drift too far off topic. After you've earned enough reputation on the site from **good** questions and answers, you can join us on the site's chat rooms, where we discuss things and go on tangents as we please (but still keeping it polite and safe for work)

Comment: @SheogorathGaming - If Charkz's answer below answers the question, you should mark it as accepted. This way, future visitors to your question know which solution worked for you :). Plus, it's a bit of a courtesy thing as it awards the user (and yourself!) with some extra reputation points :)

Answer (score 6):

It's simple. You can't get in in X and Y. In Pokemon ORAS you can get it during the Delta Episode after beating the Elite Four.

Source:Bulbapedia-http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Deoxys_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
[image: Here under X/Y you can see it only says you can get it by trade.]

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get Deoxys in x and y, but you can get it in Omega Ruby or Alpha Saffire in the delta episode and trade it over.

Comment: This answer adds nothing useful that hasn't already been said in another answer